# RAILS: Since I use Passenger, config.gem isn't allowed in the Rails:Initializers block. Why and what to change?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, passenger

it's about Ruby On Rails.

I want to use Googleauth and need to add a line starting with "config.gem" in the Rails:Initializers block in the environment.rb. Sadly, Passenger tells me that this would be an unkown command.

```
config.gem "googlebase", :lib => 'google/base', :version => '0.2'
```

What do I have to change to get, possibly because of Passenger or a newer Rails version, the gem configured?

Yours,
Joern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what version of Rails you're using. If you're trying the Rails 3 beta, you must use bundler instead of config.gem.

Bundler is a gem that manages your gem dependencies using a manifest file, called Gemfile, at the root of your app. It's kind of a moving target right now, as is Rails 3. It requires RubyGems 1.3.6, so do: `gem update --system` and `gem install bundler`, then create the Gemfile. In that file, you can do `gem "googlebase", "0.2", :require => "google/base"`.

Comment: can you tell me "bundler" als a full command, analogue to my config.gem command above?

Comment: for everyone else interested: http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/03/using-the-new-gem-bundler-today/